# Semantic UI - Search Selection not searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, search, semantic-ui

How may I make the Semantic UI Search Selection to search?

I'm currently using it inside WordPress but only the search field and the options are showing.

```js
jQuery('#search-cursos')
  .dropdown({
    fullTextSearch: true
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui fluid search selection simple dropdown">
  <input type="hidden" name="country">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Select Country</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="ad"><i class="ad flag"></i>Andorra</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="ae"><i class="ae flag"></i>United Arab Emirates</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add a fiddle (e.g. jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You currently aren't targeting the dropdown with your JS. Either add the ID to your HTML, or change your jQuery selector:

```js
// Notice the new selector
jQuery('.ui.search.dropdown')
  .dropdown({
    fullTextSearch: true
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
  <input type="hidden" name="country">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Select Country</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="ad"><i class="ad flag"></i>Andorra</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="ae"><i class="ae flag"></i>United Arab Emirates</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had the selector right, but now I think I found the issue. You put the `script` from CDN and using it, it worked. Thank you very much!